# Extracting attribute from an object for function input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm extracting an attribute from an object in Tensorflow and am trying to input it into another function. However, this attribute is extracted as a string but it works if I type it out into the function. Is there a way to "unstring" this attribute to input into the function?

Here is what I am doing that gets me a type error:

```
layer = model.layers[2]._keras_api_names[0] 
print(layer) #output: tf.keras.layers.Conv2D 
type(layer) #output: str 
function(model.layers[2]._keras_api_names[0]) #TypeError
```

This is the working code:

```
function(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D) #this works
```

Comment: "this attribute is extracted as a string"; no; the list that's labelled "_keras_api_names" *contains* strings. The value you get by doing `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` is *not the same as* the literal text `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`, in the same way that your variable `layer` is different from the string literal `"layer"`. I mean, what did you think the *names* part of `_keras_api_names` is all about?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @KarlKnechtel . I see what you are saying regarding how the value is different from the literal text. Is there a way to "convert" the value to the literal text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to convert a string name of the function to the actual function.
This can be achieved with pythons build in [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
layer_name = model.layers[2]._keras_api_names[0]
# layer name is now tf.keras.layers.Conv2D
# So we need to extract everything after last dot:
layer_name = layer_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] # now we have Conv2D
api = getattr(tf.keras.layers, layer_anme)
function(api)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, when I enter that, I get an error. "AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'keras.layers.Conv2D'". Do you know what may be causing that?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally submitted my comment before I described the problem. I have editted in an error that I just got. Do you know what may be causing the attribute error?

Comment: Yeah, the attribute you need is `Conv2D` and not the whole path to it. So need to extract this from the long string. I have updated my answer addressing the issue

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question before I accept this as the answer. I am getting "<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>" as the output for print(api). Is there a way to get it to match "tf.keras.layers.Conv2D" exactly?

Comment: [tf custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) suggest that those two are the same thing. If you `print(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D)` you should get the same long output.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the answer! I have accepted it.